# Excluding lines that start with space from egrep printout

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I'm trying to write a regex `(e)grep` command that will print all the lines in txt file, but ignore those that begin with a space (manually indented file). I haven't been able to figure out how to use the start of line `^` and exclude `^` together. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way to do this is with a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Much like `[abc]` will match `a`, `b`, or `c`, `[^abc]` will match any character that is NOT `a`, `b`, or `c`. The `^` anchors the regex at the beginning of the line, so what follows it has to match the first character of the string.

```
$ cat test
does not start with space
 starts with space
       starts with more spaces
another good line

$ egrep '^[^ ]' test
does not start with space
another good line
```

If we want to skip lines starting with whitespace, including tabs, you can use the special `[:space:]` bracket expression inside the character class:

```
 egrep '^[^[:space:]]' test
```

If you aren't looking for other things in the lines, you can also use an *inverted match*:

```
 -v, --invert-match
         Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified pat-
         terns.
```

So we could do this instead:

```
 egrep -v '^[[:space:]]' test
```

`grep` should do this too:

```
 grep -v '^[[:space:]]' test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-v` switch to skip matching lines.

```
egrep -v '^ '
```

See `man egrep`